# Can anyone provide examples of Adobe Air compiled iOS apps?

Tags: ios, flash, air, app-store

Here goes my first question. I sure hope i'm doing it right.

I've searched the web for this and found evidence of the Wired app being compiled with Adobe Flash but that's about it. There's a lot of talk on the Adobe website singing its praises but are Apple allowing these apps onto the App Store these days with the CS 5.5 update?

So, can anyone estimate how many apps floating around on the App Store that are written with Adobe Air? Any examples would be great too.

Thanks a lot
Alistair

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, AIR based apps are accepted in the App Store if they meet the general requirements. Apps are no longer rejected for not being developed using "Objective-C, C, C++, or JavaScript as executed by the iPhone OS WebKit engine", that demand has been removed.

There's quite a few games developed using AIR in the App Store, for example MeteorStorm, Gridshock, Chroma Circuit and Pyramix (Pyramix has been "featured" by Apple, see  http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=2740).

So mostly games, I don't know of many non-game apps, besides TouchUp Pro - Photo Editor, http://itunes.apple.com/app/id439242122, that also has been among the "featured" apps.

Comment: Here's another one that is not a game, the Red Bull Illume app for iPad, http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/red-bull-illume-hd/id439623304?mt=8 , that " illuminates the best 250 action and adventure sports images submitted to the Red Bull Illume Image Quest 2010". It has pretty good performance when scrolling through images and such, probably the best user experience I've seen in an AIR based app so far.

Comment: Here's a list: http://swfhead.com/blog/?p=1416

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to estimate.  I know that data is not the plural of anecdote, but I can say that my company has created a game for the web that was then subsequently published as an iOS app, which was accepted and published to the app store.  So yes, Apple is accepting them.